# Can't get media to work with Phonegap

Tags: cordova

i got big problems with playing Audio files in Phonegap. I first built my app with ionic a year ago and everything worked fine Then the app wasn't further developed until now. I compiled the app again, with the a freshly installed version of cordova, android sdk, ionic and so on. Code is still the same. Unfortunatly no sound is playing anymore. I opened a ticket at the ionic community, but didn't get an answer. I saw, that ionic isnt much developed and will suddenly cost per month, when its out of beta. Because I own a Creative suite by Adobe, I decided to go to Phonegap.

So I'm just testing around with very simple apps, based on the "Hello-World" example. I installed the cordova media plugin. Its registerd in the config.xml and in the AndroidManifest.xml

My js file:

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    var src = "android_asset/www/audio/01_Uebersicht_Heimatmuseum_maxim.mp3";

    function playAudio(url) {
    // Play the audio file at url
    var my_media = new Media(url,
    // success callback
    function () {
        alert("playAudio():Audio Success");
    },
    // error callback
    function (err) {
        alert("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
    }
);
// Play audio
my_media.play();
}


},


// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};
```

No sound is played and my alerts arent triggered.

Hope somebody can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems in your codes:

1. In your codes, you define an app object, but you are not calling the initialize function. So the function never fires. Fix: add `app.initialize()` to the end of your codes.
2. The `playAudio(url)` function is also not called in your codes. Fix: add `playAudio(src)` at the end of `onDeviceReady`(see codes below).
3. The url of your mp3 file miss the `file:///`part. To access a file in your android device you should always add `file:///` as the head of your url.

Here are the codes:

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize: function () {
    this.bindEvents();
},
// Bind Event Listeners
//
// Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
// 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
bindEvents: function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function () {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    var src = "file:///android_asset/www/Assets/Let_It_Go.mp3";
    function playAudio(url) {
        // Play the audio file at url
        var my_media = new Media(url,
        // success callback
        function () {
            alert("playAudio():Audio Success");
        },
        // error callback
        function (err) {
            alert("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
        }
    );
        // Play audio
        my_media.play();
    }

    playAudio(src);

},


// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function (id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};

app.initialize();
```

And here is the link to this complete demo: [AudioSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/StackOverFlowDemos/tree/master/CordovaDemos/AudioSample) (I created it with VS2015, So it's best to open it with VS)